# How to get Image from DataBase stored as Binary number

Tags: java, android, sql, database

I need to get an image from Data Base and display it in android application,
the image stored as binary numbers like this

```
[{"image":[83,121,115,116,101,109,46,66,121,116,101,91,93]},{"image":[83,121,115,116,101,109,46,66,121,116,101,91,93]}]
```

So how can I do this? OR is there a better method to store the image in the data base? 
Best Regards .

Comment: Check here https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-byte-to-bufferedimage-in-java/ , if stuck ask with proper code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method [BitmapFactory](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html)

```
Byte[] imageInByte = new Byte[]{83,121,115,116,101,109,46,66,121,116,101,91,93}

Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageInByte, 0, imageInByte.length);
```

Comment: then how to display it

Comment: To use this, simply use an [ImageView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html).

`ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
imageView.setImageBitmap(image);`

Comment: Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageInByte, 0, imageInByte.length);
 here tell me required byte [] but found java.lang.byte []

Comment: i changed it to byte , the error solved , 
but the image not load

Comment: [`ImageView | setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)

^ This will show you how.

Comment: byte[] imageInByte =new byte []{83,121,115,116,101,109,46,66,121,116,101,91,93};
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageInByte, 0, imageInByte.length);
        img1.setImageBitmap(image);  
this my code is there anything wrong?

Comment: Yes, the code is correct. What happens is that the byte value you have, does not form an image. You can try with this 20 pixel image. https://pastebin.com/CtFfN7tc

Answer (score 0):

To decode bitmaps on Android, use [BitmapFactory](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeByteArray(byte[],%20int,%20int)).

in your case:

`Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(YOUR_BYTE_ARRAY, 0, YOUR_BYTE_ARRAY.length);`

Comment: and "your array byte " told me , 
required byte [] but found java.lang.byte[]

Comment: how to display it ?